# Why can't I get the RSS feeds of "bicycles.stackexchange.com" using stack2rss?

Tags: support

I can easily get the feeds of stackoverflow like this

> http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/answers

But I can't feeds of bicycles in the same way WHY?

> http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/bicycles/answers

Answer (score 3):

You need to append `.stackexchange.com` to the site name:

> http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/bicycles.stackexchange.com/answers

---

**Edit:** here is the relevant section of Stack2RSS's source code that constructs the API URL to query based on the site parameter you supply:

[`src/feed.php`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/stack2rss/trunk/view/head:/src/feed.php#L178) (I've highlighted the relevant lines in bold):

```
  // Make sure the site has a TLD domain in it (for backward compatibility,
  // we insert '.com' if there isn't one. Also modify the $_GET variable to include it.
  if(substr($site, -4) != '.com')
  {
      $site .= '.com';
      $_GET['site'] .= '.com';
  }

  // Unless the site is stackauth, we prepend 'api.' to the URL
  $prepend = ($site == 'stackauth.com')?'':'api.';

  // Now construct the URL to return
  return "http://{$prepend}{$site}/{$version}/{$method}?" . implode('&', $parameters);
```

So basically what's happening here is that Stack2RSS first checks the site parameter you supply to see if it ends in `.com` (there are currently no Stack Exchange sites that end in any other TLD). So, both of the following URLs are identical and will produce the same results:

> http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/bicycles.stackexchange/answers
>   http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/bicycles.stackexchange.com/answers

The `.com` is optional - the important part is that the `.stackexchange` portion of the domain name is there, since Stack2RSS can figure the rest out from there.

Comment: Do you know why this site requires the full URL while StackOverflow, ServerFault and others don't?

Comment: @Gary.Ray: I've added a detailed explanation of the problem and what causes it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why, but that service seems to only work with the more high-traffic portions of stackexchange:

- StackOverflow - works
- ServerFault - works
- SuperUser - works
- Bicycles - does not work
- English - does not work
- Programmers - does not work
- Webmasters - does not work

I'll ask over on WebApps and see if anyone knows.